# How do I store generated Id from last query into a table in php

Tags: php, mysql

Hi how can I store a generated id from my last query to another table in mysql using php?

Here is my code (what seems to be wrong in it?

```
$regInfo = "INSERT INTO details (name, age_range_ID, sports) VALUES ('{$clean_name}', {$clean_age_range}, '{$clean_sports_list}')";

    if (!mysql_query($regInfo ,$link))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
      }
    echo "1 record added";
    $regId = mysql_insert_id();


    $modInfo = "INSERT INTO module_info (reg_ID, programme) VALUES ('{$regId }', '{$clean_programme}')";

    if (!mysql_query($modInfo ,$link))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
      }
    echo "1 record added";

    mysql_close($link)
```

Comment: what error you are getting? there is no ";" in last line.

Comment: What are the `{}` for around the variables?

Comment: there is also a space after $regId in the query, so if id=1 query will say '1 '

Comment: I cant get the $regID be saved in my  module_info table inside the column named reg_ID in mySQL. When I check it in phpMyadmin I only get 0 in the field but the rest of the fields are saved.

Comment: you are getting 0, are you sure that your 1st query is running fine? if yes then try echoing $reg_id after 1st query and share what it says

Answer (score 1):

This really isn't the best way to be doing this, it's not 1999 you know... 
So try looking into [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). If you google this topic, you'll get a bunch of tutorials on how to work with it.

And just to fix your problem for the time being, try this:

```
<?php

$regInfo = "INSERT INTO details (name, age_range_ID, sports) VALUES (`$clean_name`, `$clean_age_range`, `$clean_sports_list`)";

if (!mysql_query($regInfo ,$link))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

echo "1 record added";
$regId = mysql_insert_id();


$modInfo = "INSERT INTO module_info (reg_ID, programme) VALUES (`$regId`, `$clean_programme`)";

if (!mysql_query($modInfo ,$link))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($link);
```